# Second and first caption in long table not shown properly

Tags: tables

I would like to split my table over two pages. I am doing this by using `\usepackage{longtable}`.

However, I want the second part of the table to have a different header than the first. I tried to do it like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm,indention=0cm,font=small,labelfont=bf,format=plain,sf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}[c]{c | c | c}
\caption{My first header }\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\caption{Continued. My second header} \\ \hline
\endhead
 header & header1 & header2 \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

But then it is generated such that the newline and the line have one empty line between - and then the first row with my headers start. So it looks like:

```
--------
     --empty line here
header | header1 
---------
```

But of course I would like to get rid of that newline since it is misplaced. I tried to remove the `\\` line breaks but this cannot be compiled after that change.. I have no clue how to solve this :S. The same happens for the second header.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this:

```
  \documentclass{book}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage[margin=0.5cm,indention=0cm,font=small,labelfont=bf,format=plain,sf]{caption}


  \newcommand{\rows}{%
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  a & b & c \\
  }
 \begin{document}
  \begingroup
% \footnotesize
 \begin{longtable}{c | c | c}
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Table \thetable:} My first header}\\\hline
 header & header1 & header2 \\
 \endfirsthead
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Table \thetable:} Continued. }\\\hline
 header & header1 & header2 \\
 \endhead
  \rows
  \rows
  \rows
  \rows
  \rows
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that is exactly how I want it to look like. But is it possible to make it look like the other captions? For sure i can change the font, but like you can see in my header i defined a margin of 0.5 cm for each header, which would than not appear here, since you used multicol instead ?

Comment: @user65388 `longtable` defines its own caption which will be as wide as the long table. Hence `caption` package settings has no effect.

Comment: Ingenious: You've finessed the issue of the blank line between the caption line and the first line of the header by dispensing with the `\caption` instruction. Can one still cross-reference a `longtable` that doesn't have a `\caption`?

Comment: @Mico Not a straight job as you know. :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar caption package should have an effect on longtable: (we did share code last century) although I think ltcaption package helps in some places

Comment: @Mico yes (it's wrong really, it updates eh table counter and makes it referenceable anyway)

Answer (score 1):

There may be some confusion over header-related terminology. There's the *caption* of the table, and then there's the table's actual "header". The longtable environment automatically inserts whitespace between the caption line and the header material.

Currently, your code only has `\hline` as entire header, for both the first page and all subsequent pages of the longtable environment. Note that the row

```
header & header1 & header2 \\
```

is *not* part of the table's "header". Instead, it's the first row of the *body* of the table.

You may be looking for something like the following:

```
  \begin{longtable}{c | c | c}

  \caption{An impressive table} \\ 
  \hline
  header1 & header2 & header3 \\ 
  \hline
  \endfirsthead

  \caption{An impressive table, continued} \\
  \hline
  header4 & header5 & header6 \\ 
  \hline
  \endhead

  \hline
  \endfoot

  %% body of "longtable" environment

  \end{longtable}
```

Comment: oh yes you are right. I mixed the caption and header definition in my comment I am sorry. 
OH yes that is exactly what i wanted! Thnaks. but I don't see any difference to my code before, or is the \endfoot doing what i missed at first place?

Comment: @user65388 - I moved `header1 & header2 & header3 \\` into the material of `\endfirsthead` and created `header4 & header5 & header6 \\` as a new instruction for `\endhead`. The `\endfoot` material is indeed new, but it's not related to the header-related issues.